# using one tab as button

Tags: android, eclipse, button, tabs, android-tabhost

I've got the following code to use my tabs in my app.
I want to add one more tab and use it only as a button.

I'm trying to create this with `onTabChanged` , is that correct?

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
       public void onTabChanged(String tab2) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

My tab code is:

```
   TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("text 1").setContent(R.id.tab1));
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("text 2").setContent(R.id.tab2));
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("text 3").setContent(R.id.tab3));
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("text 4").setContent(R.id.tab4));
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator("text 5").setContent(R.id.tab5));

            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a tab as a button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're going about this the right way.  I wanted try to use a tab as a button, instead I would probably create another view, put it in line with the tabs and use it's onClickListener properly.

For instance you could try something like...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TabWidget......>
    <TextView.....>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just make sure that the "styling" is the same on both and it will be incorporated in with the tab view and look right, but not having to deal with the hole tab infrastructure.